# Log4j With Java Application Reading And writing

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have a scenario like this: This is with Java and Log4J

I have a list of id's and by passing this id's I will fetch the id's metadata. After getting the information I need to push this to other application.

My requirement is like this:

1. When a ID cannot be pushed, because of any problem occurs like network failures or some problem with that other application, then I need to write all these id's which are not pushed to a log file.
2. From the next run I must read this log file and push all the id's which are failed to be pushed in the previous run. If it is successful, then need to delete the log, if not then keep it and/or more id's not pushed.

Now, I have implemented a Log4j system which simply logs our application messages to a log file:

Code is below:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logs\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Please give me a suggestion How I can achieve this using Java code.

Comment: log4j is just for write the logs and not for read and modify the log file. Instead for log4j better if you can use simple file read/write operation as per your need.

Comment: Thank you Naveen. I will try using File operations.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Log4J for this, it is not its purpose. You should use a different storage (a separate file or a DB) to save this information in order to re-process it.
Log4J and logging in general is used to track down application execution to spot potential issues, etc. It has itw own mechanisms or writing, it rotates the log files, it adds a lot of other information, is proper for a completely different stuff.

Comment: Thank you. I will use IO mechanism here.

Comment: just mark the answer so if someone else will face a similar issue to know there is a confirmed solution and to avoid reading all the comments :) Thanks.